# I want to send a parameter to the URL and receive it on the page where I sent the parameter

Tags: php

I want to send a parameter to the URL and receive it on the page where I sent the parameter

---

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="#index.php?state=<?= $cc['id'] ?>"></a>
```

Comment: The `#` is an anchor which jumps to a point on the current page. Nothing will be sent back to the server.

Comment: What is the solution to send a parameter in the current document?

Answer (score 0):

your href contains an "#" insted of a slash

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php?state=<?php echo $cc['id']; ?>"></a>
```